# Add commit author name without specifying the entire format

Tags: git, git-log

folks!
I'm using the following command: `git log my-branch-name HEAD --graph --oneline`, and I'm quite happy with the output format produced. Lets me compare the two branches and generates a fancy graph while keeping the command short and easy to memorize.

I'd like to add the author to the output. I know it is possible to do so using the `pretty` option, but, as far as I understood, I would be forced to specify the entire commit format, then having to memorize (or save as an alias, which I'm not very willing to do) a long and awkward formatting string.

Is there any way to just add the author information, without having to specify every single aspect of the output?

Sorry if there is already a similar question, my Googling skills failed me on this.

Comment: What's wrong with an alias? `git config alias.mylog 'log --graph --pretty='format:%h%an%ad%s'` once and then `git mylog HEAD` anytime again

Comment: I wanted a way to perform the action, not a fixed command. Every time I want to twitch anything in the command - say, remove the graph part or anything, I'll be forced to type the command. And I do it a lot, so... I use aliases for other stuff, but I'm not trying to find a specific way to achieve it and then forget it - I want to know if there is an option for that, or not. 
That said, I'd still have to tweak that command you mentioned - it does not color nor shows the branches' names.

Comment: Then define an alias for the part that want to have "fixed" and provide the other options as you go. E.g. `git config alias.lg 'log --pretty="format:%h%an%ad%s"'` and then run `git lg --graph --decorate`, `git lg --patch`, `git lg --pretty-much-anything`, or even `git lg --pretty='format:…'`. AFAIK there's no way to specify a "default format" for git log and friends. Either you use the predefined ones or specify it explicitly every time _or_ you define a shell or git alias or function

Comment: `Not possible` seems to be the answer, I see. I mean, people are trying to help me to accomplish it - but I know how to accomplish it, I was looking for alternative ways; I thought I had left that clear on the question. I was trying to learn about the existence of another command of option I wasn't aware of. I even got a downvote for that, and was called lazy by a guy suggesting that I do exactly what I said I did not want to do.
I can use an alias, but, should I try to help a friend on their PC, that won't help. I'm trying to learn something, not to get some a fixed formula for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can `format` the `--pretty` parameter, like so:

```
git log your-branch-name HEAD --graph --pretty=format:"%h%an%ad%s"
```

Click [**Place Holder**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) and scroll down a little bit, it shows you what each placeholder means.

You can add the placeholder `%C` to color each part of your output, like so:

```
git log YourBranch HEAD --graph --pretty=format:"%C(red)%h%C(yellow)%an%C(green)%ad%C(blue)%s"
```